# mySQL multiple AND comparisons in WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have the following mySQL statement which is incorrect.

```
SELECT id, location__, image__, bedrooms, bathrooms, price__ 
FROM myTable 
WHERE LOWER(location__) REGEXP '.london.' 
AND (bedrooms >=2) 
AND (bathrooms == true) 
ORDER BY price__  DESC 
LIMIT 0,20;
```

How do I format a SQL query that works in PHP so that I can compare bedrooms > 2 AND bathrooms > 2 AND ensuites = 1 (i.e. true)... etc

Comment: why or?  logically I want 2+ bedrooms and 2+ bathrooms

Comment: There is no `==` in MYSQL. Isn't `WHERE bedrooms >= 2 AND bathrooms >= 2 AND ensuites = 1` working..?

Comment: How would this look in php?? This query another question I know

Comment: What do you mean how would this look in PHP? You put it as the querystring and execute the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add condition as you like with AND to fulfill your requirement here.

```
SELECT id, location__, image__, bedrooms, bathrooms, price__ 
FROM myTable 
WHERE LOWER(location__) REGEXP '.london.' 
AND bedrooms >=2
AND bathrooms >=2 and ensuites = 1
ORDER BY price__  DESC 
LIMIT 0,20;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be using a wrong SQL comparison operator with bathrooms. In SQL you compare with a single equal-sign:

```
SELECT id, location__, image__, bedrooms, bathrooms, price__ 
FROM myTable 
WHERE LOWER(location__) REGEXP '.london.' 
AND bedrooms >= 2 
AND bathrooms = 1 
ORDER BY price__  DESC 
LIMIT 0,20;
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/comparison_operators.php